# Font name on the following image

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What is the name of the font or the similar font of the text on the attached photo.
I found it on a paper and I liked it and want to have it in my computer.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. We have some special [requirements for font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/89608). It would be great if you could read these, and [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/122299/edit) to provide the missing information. Thanks.

Comment: ...and attach the photo... [I found it & reattached, in edit queue]

Comment: You edited the image off. But the red text had nearly as bad kerning as some of my home made font attempts. (kerning=spacing variations to make the typesetting look out well balanced ). I wouldn't accept it. It can be in the font or in the software which uses it. Or is it perfect, but a way to describe some language specific richness which isn't needed in western writings?

Answer (score 1):

According to me the font should be be **[Gill Sans Infant Std](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/gill-sans-infant/)**

Watch the demo below; 90% of glyphs seems matching; but it might not exact you want but it might help you;
good luck to others who trying to find this font
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I see is  this one.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if this is the font you was looking :)

Comment: @BenifaMD not upvote but mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yeah even better :)